Do hot air balloons have flight data recorders and cockpit voice recorders?
I'm wondering if hot air balloons also have flight data recorders and cockpit voice recorders like commercial jet aircraft. I mean, if there isn't one and an accident happens, how are investigators supposed to know what happened? Also, if there is one, where is it stored? I know that FDRs and CVRs are usually stored in the tail on commercial aircraft, but a hot air balloon does not have a tail, so where are they stored? Does anyone know anything about this? I would like to know. Thanks in advance!

Would the downvoter please add some feedback as to why this is a bad question?

Yeah, downvoters, please add some suggestions for improvement or other advice so I can improve next time.

Flight recorders aren't very common outside of airliners and military aircraft, since their installation is fairly complex. Per balloon regulations, they don't require certified CVR or FDR.
Hot air balloons don't have much in the way of instruments, traditionally just an altimeter and a variometer. Today, they usually use a handheld-style GPS unit, which has its own recording capability, but isn't hardened like commercial FDR. There's no need for a CVR, as balloons only need a single operator, so there's no crew communications to record. They are passively safe (most failures lead to a slow descent), and any accident's cause is normally quite obvious.
It's like why horses aren't fitted with dashboards. Perhaps you could strap one on, but should you? That said, you can use a handheld device to navigate, and that's what balloon operators do.

Audio recording could be useful to provide non-invasive data on burner firing. It would also record radio and voice communication with ground crew, which is critical to safe takeoff and landing (e.g. avoiding power lines).

@user71659 Perhaps. But burner failure is a non-issue, it just results in a forced landing. Comms with ground crew might matter, but it's way easier to install a dictaphone app on a crew's phone (or request the recording from the carrier, phone calls aren't really private) than a FAA-certified black box on the balloon.

Crew's phone? Hot air balloons don't rely on cell phones for important reasons: poor coverage at altitude due to overlapping cell site visibility and potentially landing somewhere without coverage. They're supposed to use airband radio, many use services like commercial 2-way FM and FRS instead.

@user71659 Yeah, they do occasionally use a CB walkie-talkie. The safety culture in there is slightly below zero.
